# Error in printing values within complex heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, complexheatmap

I am trying to use the `ComplexHeatmap` R package to generate heatmaps and also print the values.

`NES_final` is a list of list containing `expt` at first level and `scenario` at second level. Within each `expt` I need to create a combined heatmap of all `scenario`.

The heatmap is created as expected, but while printing only the last value of `scenario` in each `expt` gets printed for all heatmaps within that `expt`.

**Test data:**

```
NES_final = list("expt1" = list("scenario1" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3),
                                "scenario2" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3),
                                "scenario3" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3)),
                 "expt2" = list("scenario1" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3),
                                "scenario2" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3),
                                "scenario3" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3)),
                 "expt3" = list("scenario1" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3),
                                "scenario2" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3),
                                "scenario3" = matrix(rnorm(36), nrow=3, ncol=3)))
```

**Code:**

```
    for(expt in names(NES_final)){
      NES <- NES_final[[expt]]      
      heatMap <- NULL
      for(scenario in names(NES)){       
        heatMap <- heatMap + Heatmap(NES[[scenario]],
                                     cluster_rows = FALSE,
                                     cluster_columns = FALSE,
                                     name = scenario,
                                     column_title = scenario,
                                     show_heatmap_legend = TRUE,
                                     cell_fun =  function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill){
                                       grid.text(scenario, x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 2))
                                     }
                                     )
      }
      
      svglite(paste0("/Analysis_1/Heatmap_", expt, ".svg"), width = length(NES) * 25, height = 6)
      draw(heatMap, column_title = expt)
      dev.off()
    }
```

Comment: Please fix your indentations and spacing, the code is hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution using the `lapply` function instead of the for loop for scenario.

```
heatMap <- lapply(names(NES), function(scenario){
         Heatmap(NES[[scenario]],
              cluster_rows = TRUE,
              cluster_columns = FALSE,
              name = scenario,
              column_title = scenario,
              show_heatmap_legend = FALSE,
              cell_fun =  function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill){
                grid.text(scenario, x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 5))
              } ) })  }
 
  heatMap <- Reduce("+", heatMap)
  draw(heatMap, column_title = expt, padding = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 15), "cm"))
```